# Django: blocktrans entry is not being translated

Tags: django, django-i18n

I have this block in my HTML

```
...
<a class="header" href="{% url 'listing' house_post.id %}">
  {% blocktrans with house_type=house_post.house_type.name trimmed %}
    {{house_type}}
  {% endblocktrans %}
</a>
...
```

One value of *house_type* is "Condominium". I've added the following entry in my .po file.

```
msgid "Condominium"
msgstr "ኮንዶሚኒየም"
```

I've run **compilemessages** on the po file, and the rest of the translations work when I switch languages. And I've made sure the value of *house_type* is set to "Condominium". But for some reason it's not being translated.

In addition when I run **makemessages** the tool comments out additions I've made in the .po files. I'm uncommenting them before running **compilemessages**. I don't know why it's doing that though it might be a clue.

It is possible to add translation texts to .po files. Isn't it?

Comment: It works when I put the variable inside trans directly.

    {% trans house_post.house_type.name %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not translated because `{{house_type}}` will have the value of `house_post.house_type.name`.

The blocktrans actually does nothing in your code. You would need it if you want to add a translatable text to the sentence. Ex:

```
  {% blocktrans with house_type=house_post.house_type.name trimmed %}
    {{house_type}} Translate this part
  {% endblocktrans %}
```

If you want to have a translated variable, you have to pass the translations to `house_post.house_type.name`.

Answer (score 0):

The content of your blocktrans is most likely the content of `{{house_type}}`. Not sure where it comes from, but this is where you have to translate it. Don't forget to insert something like

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

to header of your py-files.